# Overriden method still gets called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchbase, ruby-2.0

I am using a library that is implementing a `belongs_to` association between two entries in a database. Since this is not the behaviour I need I want to override this method via `prepend`. But pry tells me that the original method is still called. I double checked and I'm using ruby 2.0.

The code that gets prepended:

```
module Associations
  module ClassMethods

    [...]
    #Add the attributeName to the belongsToAttributes
    #and add a field in the list for the IDs
    def belongs_to(attr_name)
      @belongsToAttributes ||= []
      @belongstoAttributes << attr_name

      create_attr attr_name.to_s
      attribute belongs_to_string.concat(attr_name.to_s).to_sym
    end

    def belongsToAttributes
      @belongsToAttributes
    end    
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

# prepend the extension 
Couchbase::Model.send(:prepend, Associations)
```

I use this in this class:

**Note:** I also tried to directly override the method in this class but it still doesn't happen

```
require 'couchbase/model'

class AdServeModel < Couchbase::Model

[...]
  #I tried to add the belongs_to method like this
  #def belongs_to(attr_name)
  #   @belongsToAttributes ||= []
  #   @belongstoAttributes << attr_name

  #   create_attr attr_name.to_s
  #    attribute belongs_to_string.concat(attr_name.to_s).to_sym
  #  end

  #  def belongsToAttributes
  #    @belongsToAttributes
  #  end
end
```

When I check with pry it shows me that I end up in [this](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model/blob/master/lib/couchbase/model.rb#L386) method call:

```
def self.belongs_to(name, options = {})
  ref = "#{name}_id"
  attribute(ref)
  assoc = name.to_s.camelize.constantize
  define_method(name) do
    assoc.find(self.send(ref))
  end
end
```

Any pointer to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Ok I solved the problem like this:

```
 self.prepended(base)
    class << base
      prepend ClassMethods
    end
  end

end
# prepend the extension 
Couchbase::Model.send(:prepend, Associations)
```

Since **Arie Shaw**'s post contains important pointers to solve this problem I will accept his answer. Although he missed the point about extending and prepending the method that I want to call. For a more detailed discussion about my trouble with prepending the methods please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683750/how-to-prepend-classmethods) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the pry trace you posted, the method you wanted to monkey patch is a class method of `AdServeModel`, not a instance method.

- The problem with your `Associations` module approach is, you are calling `Module#prepend` to `prepend` the module to the existing class, however, you wrote a `self.included` hook method which will only be called when the module is included (not prepended). You should write [`Module#prepended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepended) hook instead.
- The problem with the directly overriding approach is, you were actually overriding the instance method, rather than the class method. It should be something like this:

```rb
require 'couchbase/model'

class AdServeModel < Couchbase::Model
  class << self
    # save the original method for future use, if necessary
    alias_method :orig_belongs_to, :belongs_to

    def belongs_to(attr_name)
      @belongsToAttributes ||= []
      @belongstoAttributes << attr_name

      create_attr attr_name.to_s
      attribute belongs_to_string.concat(attr_name.to_s).to_sym
    end

    def belongsToAttributes
      @belongsToAttributes
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh yes I see, it's called `alias_method_chaining` I think? I actually try to avoid that. I changed the hook to Module#prepend already but alas to no avail. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683750/how-to-prepend-classmethods question where I try to find an answer to the more basic problem.