# How to prepend classmethods

Tags: ruby

This question directly relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682494/overriden-method-still-gets-called). But I tried to break it down to the base problem and I didn't want to enter even more text into the other question box. So here goes:

I know that I can include classmethods by extending the module ClassMethods and including it via the Module#include hook. But can I do the same with prepend? Here is my example:

class Foo:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    'Base Bar!'
  end
end
```

class Extensions:

```
module Extensions
  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      'Extended Bar!'
    end
  end

  def self.prepended(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
# prepend the extension 
Foo.send(:prepend, Extensions)
```

class FooE:

```
require './Foo'

class FooE < Foo
end
```

and a simple startscript:

```
require 'pry'
require './FooE'
require './Extensions'

puts FooE.bar
```

When I start the script I don't get `Extended Bar!` like I expect but rather `Base Bar!`. What do I need to change in order to work properly?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that even though you're prepending the module, `ClassMethods` is still getting `extend`ed in. You could do this to get what you want:

```
module Extensions
  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      'Extended Bar!'
    end  
  end  

  def self.prepended(base)
    class << base
      prepend ClassMethods
    end  
  end  
end
```

Note that `Extensions` itself could be either prepended or included in `Foo`. The important part is prepending `ClassMethods`.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot. Obviously I didn't know what extend does.

Answer (score 44):

A simpler version:

```
module Extensions
  def bar
    'Extended Bar!'
  end  
end

Foo.singleton_class.prepend Extensions
```

Comment: This answer works in case of modifying `inherited` hook of target class. other answer which uses `self.prepended` hook to solve this, doesn't work with it.