# ActiveRecord::Migration prepend context and method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building up a library to add a functionality to `ActiveRecord::Migration` but I'm struggling to understand the behavior.

When the library is loaded, I execute the following code

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.prepend MyLibrary::Mutators
end
```

Then in `my_library/mutators.rb`

```
module MyLibrary
  module Mutators
    def do_something
      # do stuff here and use `self`
    end
  end
end
```

The goal here is very simple, I need to be able to call this method within my migrations classes

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  do_something

  def change
    create_table 'async_test' do |t|
      t.string :test
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this migration, it'll effectively call `do_something`

The problem is when I try to get some context about what is run, which's necessary for my library to execute other stuff, `self` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Migration` and not `Test`, but the class using this method is `Test`.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x00007fac5b83df38
 @connection=nil,
 @name="ActiveRecord::Migration",
 @version=nil>
```

If I change things around and call `do_something` within `#change` it'll consider `self` as the instance of `Test` which's what I would have liked on class level.

How can I get `do_something` to return `self` as `Test` at class level by extending `ActiveRecord::Migration` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you call `prepend` on a class only instance methds are prepended, so you should not be able to call do_something in Test class context. Is this code working now?

Comment: It does work, it's been several days i'm working on this and just spotted this issue, the behavior is weird enough to make me doubt about how Ruby works globally. I can actually call `do_something` at class level and instance level

Comment: I've just checked it. For some reason it's possible to call prepended methods on ActiveRecord::Migration class, but not on other classes in Rails. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Migration.method_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L603-L605) (on class level) calls [`nearest_delegate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L573-L575) that seems to be an instance of `ActiveRecord::Migration`

```
 > ActiveRecord::Migration.nearest_delegate
 => #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x0000561889aa1930 @connection=nil, @name="ActiveRecord::Migration", @version=nil>
```

When you call `ActiveRecord::Migration.prepend MyLibrary::Mutators` you prepend instance methods of `ActiveRecord::Migration` with `MyLibrary::Mutators`. so `do_something` is defined on an migration instance.

When you call:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  do_something
  # ...
end
```

`Test.method_missing` is called, it calls `#do_something` on `nearest_delegate` that appears to be `ActiveRecord::Migration` instance.

If you want to have `do_something` really defined on migration class level, you need to properly prepend class methods. It is described precisely in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683750/how-to-prepend-classmethods).

Long story short, you should call `.prepend` in migration singleton class, not on migration class:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.singleton_class.prepend MyLibrary::Mutators
end
```

Comment: That's ... Absolutely what I needed to know to unlock the situation. I actually wanted to `prepend` the classes migrations at some point but didn't find a good way to do so. Thanks you so much.